# Extract only text from HTML file with BeatifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a little problem. Here my html file :

```
<div class="titreArticle">   
<p class="titreArticleVisu rdp__articletitle">Analysis of proposed SBP Amendment Act</p>  
</div>
```

With beautifusoup, I want to explore my file in order to take some text in tags.

Here my code in Python :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import calendar
import locale
from lxml import etree
import string

mess = "Entrez le chemin vers le fichier HTML Europress : "
html_source = "/Users/alancuzon/Desktop/test.HTML"
html = open(html_source, "r")
content = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")


#soup.find_all('span', class_='apd-sources-date', text=True)

exported_articles = []
articles = soup.findAll("article")
for a in articles:
    article = {}

    journal_title = a.find("span", {"class", "DocPublicationName"}).text
    article["journal"] = journal_title
    
    article_date = a.find("span", {"class", "DocHeader"}).text
    article["date"] = article_date
    
    
    exported_articles.append(article)
```

But I have an error when I want to take the text of the example tag. My error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-ff7c57861c92> in <module>
     23     article["journal"] = journal_title
     24 
---> 25     article_date = a.find("span", {"class", "DocHeader"}).text
     26     article["date"] = article_date
     27 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

When I delete the .text, I have only the string of the html.
Did you know how to fix that ? In order to keep only the string ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't.. It's a private website

Comment: This `article_date = a.find("span", {"class", "DocHeader"})` attempts to select an element that might not be there, hence the error. Double check your HTML.

Comment: You can try to climb to the parent container and use `.text` there if there's no other text in child elements besides the one you're trying to parse. Also, you can inspect this element and copy `XPath` by `right-clicking -> copy -> copy XPath` in the Chrome dev tools or whatever browser you use. OR, you can use `CSS` selectors to grab it (again, *right-click*) or [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The `ArributeError` is caused by the previous selector returning `None`. I think it might be because you're not using the correct selectors to find an element by class name.

You're using:

```
{"class", "DocHeader"}
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class), it should either be

```
attrs={"class": "DocHeader"}
```

or

```
class_="DocHeader"
```

Try using

```
for a in articles:
    article = {}

    journal_title = a.find("span", attrs={"class": "DocPublicationName"}).text
    article["journal"] = journal_title
    
    article_date = a.find("span", attrs={"class": "DocHeader"}).text
    article["date"] = article_date
    
    
    exported_articles.append(article)
```

You can also use css selectors if that's easier:

```
a.select_one(".DocHeader")
```

If you still get `None`, then it means the selected element doesn't exist - double check if the class name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Parzival's answer is true. You must use `{"class":"DocHeader"}` instead of `{"class","DocHeader"}` .
And you should consider closing the file. You can add an `html.close()`  just before creating the soup.
Lastly I recommend you to use `.getText(' ', strip=True)`  instead of `.text` .